# sql query to get the address of customer

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables i.e. `table A` and `table B`. `Table B` has primary key of `table A` as `Id` column.

I want to get the name and address from two tables.[image]

How can I achieved this?

I tried:

```
select name,address from tableA join tableB on tableA.id=tableB.id
```

Comment: Hint : `JOIN` (i.e. `INNER/OUTER`).

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: can you update your question with desire output?

Comment: Assuming the information about column names you have given us is correct, then it should work, unless one of the tables is empty or there are no data matches.  Are you sure Table B's ID column isn't just a primary key for Table B and there's another column on the table that references Table A's ID?

Comment: yes id of table A  is present in table B as column name id

Answer (score 0):

Your own answer is correct.

Here's the tables you described with the relationships:

[image: Your basic as ever table diagram]

I filled the tables with some guid's and copy pasted your own SQL

> (50 rows affected)

Try this
Check `tableA` has values

```
Select COUNT(*) from [tableA]
```

And `tableB`

```
Select COUNT(*) from [tableB]
```

if they both have a count > 0
How many items in `tableA` have at least one value in `tableB`

```
--Show all the raw data
Select tableA.*,(select count(*) from tableB where tableA.id = tableB.id)VolumeOfAddresses
FROM tableA
--or Group and count it
Select VolumeOfAddresses,count(*) NameCount
FROM (Select tableA.*,(select count(*) from tableB where tableA.id = tableB.id)VolumeOfAddresses
FROM tableA) a
group by a.VolumeOfAddresses
--or express that as a string of text for simplicity
Select cast(count(*) as varchar(10)) + ' Names exists which each have an address COUNT of ' + cast(VolumeOfAddresses as varchar(10))A_TextString
FROM (Select tableA.*,(select count(*) from tableB where tableA.id = tableB.id)VolumeOfAddresses
FROM tableA) a
group by a.VolumeOfAddresses
```

The example result from the last query in my testing shows:

- 50 Names exists which each have an address COUNT of 0
- 50 Names exists which each have an address COUNT of 1